# I have an angular factory and I want to mock it in real browser, not in the testing

Tags: angularjs, mocking

I don't have mocha or jasmine, I want to run my angular app and mock some factories/services in the real browser. Currently I swap those that I need to mock for the ones with same name. This requires replacing them in index.html in my build process.

Can I somehow use angular.mock inside real browser to mock it, so that I don't have to replace  real implementations in the build?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to mock your services in production ?

Comment: Not in production. In browser. We are developing angular app for our own build of chromium. In that said chromium we have some special global JS functions. It is our api for comunicating with our service. So for debugging the app in the browser, we need to mock services which use this api, which is of course missing in Chrome/FF/IE whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you could use a **[decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/%24provide#decorator)**.

> A service decorator intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it to override or modify the behaviour of the service. The object returned by the decorator may be the original service, or a new service object which replaces or wraps and delegates to the original service.

E.g.:

```
/* The original service using "native" `window.alert` */
.factory('GreetingSrv', function ($window) {
    return {
        sayHi: function (name) {
            $window.alert('Hi, ' + name + ' !');
        }
    };
});

/* Let's tinker with that service to make it use
 * our custom-made `window.createStylishModal` !! */
.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('GreetingSrv', function ($delegate, $window) {
        /* Let's monkey-patch the original service
         * to use our custom browser-API */
        $delegate.sayHi = function (name) {
            $window.createStylishModal('Hello, ' + name + ' !');
        };

        /* Return the monkey-patched service
         * (Note: we could have returned a 
         *  totally different object as well) */
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes! Finally a valid answer!